# Format for more than 24 hours

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dataformat

In my database i store time that people have to spend on a task in minutes. For example 600 minutes.
When I create this task I want the user to fill in Hours follow by minutes for example:
30:20 or 30 or 1:20. 
In order to do this i did the following

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan AllocatedTime { get; set; }

public int AllocatedMinutes { get; set; }
```

When the user enters his information in the field he uses allocatedtime, which is later converted to minutes in the Controller.

The problem is though, whenever the entered time is more than 23:59 it will give an error that it's in the wrong format.
I've tried to several things to solve this but it didn't work out, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I (personally) find your timespan input format very confusing and I wouldn't want to use it. I think you'd be better off with a different setup, rather than trying to solve this problem. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Well I could use a string instead of timespan instead, but it would need to accept hh:mm and hhh:mm and hh

Comment: Maybe something like `30h 20m` and then you can parse it into an actual timespan by reading the various parts of the duration.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but a suggestion for a different approach. I think your attempt to get duration in the form of `hh:mm` would be confusing to users (I would raise an eyebrow if I saw `327:15` - this is not a natural way to read time. It's also cumbersome when you talk about more than a day or two.

I'd suggest to use a different duration format; something like `Xd Yh Zm` where `X`, `Y` and `Z` are days, hours and minutes, respectively. Each part could be optional, but this would make it a lot easier for users to enter the timespan in question, since they'd be entering natural time units.

You could then use a regular expression to try to get the various parts and build an actual `TimeSpan` out of the values.

This regex could be a start:

```
(?:(?<days>\d+)d\s)?\s*(?:(?<hours>\d+)h\s)?\s*(?:(?<minutes>\d+)m)?
```

Note: I only tested this for a few minutes so it may not cover all the possibilities but it should be a good enough start.

Comment: I'd say this is a bit weird. Because for example you have to work on a task for 60 hours. You dont want to put in 2:08:00, that kinda makes no sense. And its saved in minutes in the database as an int.

Comment: @vincentdeg No, you wouldn't use `:` as a separator at all - that's exactly what makes me think your approach confusing - it looks like time instant when it's a duration. I used `d` for days, `h` for hours and `m` for minutes with simple whitespace as separators. Your example would be `2d 8h` which is easy to read / type and easy to parse into an actual `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @vincentdeg There are various systems using this input format (Jira, for example) and it works well.

Comment: It doesn't have to parse it in a timespan, it has to parse it in to    Minutes, integer.

Comment: @vincentdeg You would parse it in to a TimeSpan then read the value from the `TotalMinutes` property. It will be a double because it includes the seconds part in the decimal, but you can just cast it to a int to truncate it.

Comment: @vincentdeg If you parse it into a `TimeSpan` you can easily convert it to just minutes.

Comment: I've been trying to make a regular expression for..               [0-9]{1-3} and then if a : is typed it requires 2 more numbers.     "[0-9]{1-3}(?(:):[0-9]{2})"  "[0-9]{1-3}:?(?(:)[0-9]{2})"          Can't seem to figure out how though

Comment: @vincentdeg The above regex gives you days, hours and minutes that you can easily plug into a `TimeSpan`. Try it here with some sample input: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying... i finnally figured it out :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?(:[0-5][0-9])?$", ErrorMessage = "wrong")]
```

Comment: Good that you figured it out but I agree with xxbbcc in that your format is confusing. 900:25 is very hard for a human to convert to a meaningful interval.

Comment: @ErocGtx2 The thing is you're not gonna work on 1 task for longer then 50 hours. So in that case it would be weird to type 2:2:00 instead of just 50 for 50 hours